# W3C Validator returns an error in index.html, at app-root

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I try to validate my html page but when i retrieve the following error:

```
Error: Element app-root not allowed as child of element body in this context. 
(Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

From line 4347, column 7; to line 4347, column 16

r">↩      <app-root>

Content model for element div:
Flow content.
Neither tag is omissible.
```

This is the html of my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

How I can, if it is possible, bypass the test?

Comment: `app-root` is not an HTML tag.

Comment: `app-root` isn't a part of the HTML spec, so it is invalid by definition

Comment: You'll want to run the validator on the rendered HTML Angular eventually outputs to the DOM, if you must run the validator.

Comment: Heretic Monkey, you mean the outerHTML? Because i try with this but he doesn't work the same.

Comment: You'll want to use @ followed by the username to respond in comments... I'm not sure what the "he" is that doesn't work the same. In any case, you have an answer now...

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow... sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Angular has a way to create custom elements to reuse the components, app-root tag is a custom element for Angular to render the App Component which is the root component of the project.

You can find this selector when going to `src\app\app.component.ts` file and check the `selector` property inside `@Component`. 
`app-root` can be changed to any name you want by changing the `selector` property and the tag name.

The HTML validator will search for any unfamiliar tags and complain about it, even though it is a custom element that is used inside Angular.

Comment: You may want to advise the OP that this can be a valid HTML tag with an attribute, like `<div id="app-root"></div>` and they can change the `selector` to `#app-root`. Then the validator will have no complaints.

Comment: @HereticMonkey works for app-root, but the problem persists for router-outlet directive, that is invoked in app-component.